# Auto-populate a field in a form with user input from a seperate form Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

My Set-up:
I have two tables: tblAuthors and tblBooks. tblAuthors includes a list authors: Kurt Vonnegut, Frank Herbert, J. K. Rowling, John Nichols, etc.. tblBooks includes a list of books: Slaughter House Five, Cat's Craddle, Monkey House, Dune, Harry Potter, Milagro Beanfield War, etc..

I have two forms as well: frmAuthor and frmBooks. frmAuthor includes the name of the author as well as some more author specific information that isn't particularly relevant to this question (date of birth, place of birth, preffered genre, inspirations, etc.). frmBooks includes the authors name(s) as well as some other information (publishing company, date completed, genre).

There is also a one-to-many relationship between tblBooks and tblAuthors; Authors in tblAuthors is used as the primary key for this relationship. Just to give you a better idea on how these tables enteract and the thought behind the organization of the database.

The way these forms interact is as follows:
The intended way to update this database is to input information by book into frmBooks. If the author for the book is missing a window will come up prompting the user to add a new author from the NotInList event. If the user hits 'yes' the frmAuthors will pop. The user will input the Authors information and then hit the "done" command at the bottom of the form which will return the user back to frmBooks to complete entering the data for the other book.

I am looking for a way to auto-populate the field "Author" based on the input from the NotInList event. Currently it is saved as a temporary variable and author input on the second form saves it in the table. I simply want to simplify the process and have the input in the first form carry over and automatically populate the same field in the second form.

I am not really familiar with VBA and could use an explantion that is geared towards someone who may not understand all of the facets of the code.

Thank you in advance for any help that you give me!

Comment: There is code freely available for most standard events: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197526

Comment: Because your tblAuthors table is going to be holding Primary Key information that is used as a Foreign Key in tblBooks, it would be a better practice (for referential integrity) that the author data be entered first, not book.  Use a combo box in frmBooks to hold a list of all known authors.  If the author is missing from that list, have the user go to frmAuthors to enter in the data first.  The combo box serves an important role here by not allowing the users to key in the same author every time, eliminating possible spelling mistakes that could create new redundant records.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to a field in another form, use -

```
Forms![frmBooks]![txtAuthor].Text
```